# Robot Framework, SikuliLibrary doesn' t work click region

Tags: windows, robotframework, sikuli, region

With a Library SikuliLibrary in Robot Framework, click Region It Works with image (${buttom_8})

```
${pref_coordinates}    Get Image Coordinates    ${buttom_8}
SikuliLibrary.Click Region   ${pref_coordinates}
```

But If I try without image doesn't work.

```
*** Variables ***
@{first_coordinates} Create List ${344} ${730}

*** Test Cases ***
tryy4

*** Keywords ***
tryy4
 Click Region @{first_coordinates}
```

what am I doing wrong?
console error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Answer (score 0):

If you debug your image coordinates (region), you will see it returns a list with four elements: origin (x,y) and width (Lx,Ly):

```
${pref_coordinates}    Get Image Coordinates    ${buttom_8}
Log    ${pref_coordinates}
```

Here is an example taken from RIDE:
[image: Scrrenshot of RIDE at Text Editor showing Click Region documentation]